# Unit testing Angular app for dynamic contents

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-test

I am running unit test on angular app for UI part, when try to get the DOM elements using fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.someClass')), altough someClass is defined inside template.html debug Element returns null.

I also see that angular generates someClass dynamically, but I want to run on this to spyon some method call. How to test them?
Note: I am using JAsmine and Karma

Comment: please share your code